# Transfer sql server express between machines

Tags: sql-server, database, express, transfer, migrate

I am really new to this so please forgive this question.

We have sql server express 2008 running on a server which forms the back end database to a Access project (apd) application that sits on numerous client machines where user logins are controlled by usernames and passwords.

We need to decommission the server and are looking to transfer the database onto a new machine and then change the client app to point to the new server.

We think we've sorted the re-pointing issue but need some help on how to transfer the database "lock, stock and barrel" to the new machine running sql server express as well.

Any advice would be gratefully received. Thanks in advance.
Harv

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Sql Server 2008 Express on the new server
2. Make sure you can connect to it from SSMS from outside of the server
3. On the old server, backup your database do a .bak file (you can do this from SSMS, right click on your database)
4. Move the .bak file to the file system of the new server
5. In SSMS, restore the new database (right click server name -> restore)
6. Update Sql Server user-access permissions so that your connection-string user has proper access to that database
7. Update the relevant connection strings in your application to refer to the new database server (IP address change? server name change? etc)

Comment: Thanks Brian.  Well give this a go.  On point 7 I was thinking of renaming the new server as the old server and taking the old server down.  This will save me having to repoint the connection strings in the application as there are about 40 to do!